# Angular 8: Show/Hide Input based on Checkbox selected

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, angular-forms, dynamic-forms

I am trying to bind input fields to a list of checkbox fields generated from API.
As the code shows below, it will generate 7 checkbox field.

```
  <form [formGroup]="actForm">
                <mat-label class="activityCheckBox"
                  formArrayName="func1Activities"
                  *ngFor="let act of actForm.controls.activity.controls; let i = index;">
                  <tpcr-input-checkbox [formControlName]="i"></tpcr-input-checkbox>
                  {{activity[i].Name}}

                  <mat-form-field ngDefaultControl class="example-full-width" type="number">
                    <input matInput class="timeInput" type="number"
                      [(ngModel)]="formProfile.timeSpent" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
                  </mat-form-field>

                </mat-label>
  </form>
```

Right now, the input fields are all generated along with the activity checkbox in the ngFor loop. Is there anyway to ONLY display the specific input field if one of the checkbox is selected?

For example,   Activity 1 Checkbox = checked ----> Input Field Appears 
               Activity 2 Checkbox = unchecked ---> Input Field Hide

This is bothering me for some time now, I really appreciate your time and help!!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you has a form like

```
actForm=new FormGroup({
  activity=new FormArray([new FormControl(),new FormControl()]
})
```

So, you can access into the *ngFor like

```
actForm.get('activity').at(i).value
```

or

```
act.value
```

When you iterate over `let control of actForm.get('activity').controls` control is, if our formArray is a FormArray of FormControls the own control -if our formArray is a formArray of formGroup I like name as `let group of actForm.get('activity').controls`, so "group" is the formGroup

Note, if you only has an FormArray you need'n create a formGroup, you can directly

```
  activity:FormArray=new FormArray([new FormControl(),new FormControl()]
```

And

```
 <div *ngFor="let control of activity.controls;let i=index">
     <input [formControl]="control">
 </div>
```

Comment: if I understand correctly,  activity FormArray will contain two new FormControl() for each act? one is checkbox and the other one is input field?  How would I toggle the input field based on the checkbox selected? thanks for your answer!

Comment: no, sorry, I explain bad. if a formArray with two elements, each one is a FormControl. The json value of actForm is {activity:['','']}. normally you has some like `activity=new FormArray([]);activity.push(new FormControl());activity.push(new FormControl())` or `activity=data.map(x=> new FormControl())` is an array of FormControls. Well really is a "super array" -has properties that the arrays has no